# simplehtmldom Combine Tables into a Single Table in simplehtmldom

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I am using `SimpleHTMLdom` and extracting html file.
My code is as follows:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');          
$curl = curl_init();

$link = "http://example.com/q/?id=123456");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "$link");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$file_contents = curl_exec($curl);     
$html = str_get_html($file_contents);    
$elem = $html->find('div[id=hCStatus_result]', 0)->innertext;  
echo $elem;
```

Actually the Page which I am extracting has a Div which is extracted but in the result I am getting a lot of tables. with same TD class.. I want to make them as a single table ..

Structure is as follows:

```
<div id="hCStatus_result" style="height:120px;overflow:auto;">
<table style="width:100%;" >
<tr > <td width="7%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">1</td><td width="30%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">Name1</td><td width="20%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">Details</td> <td width="43%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">Status OK</td></tr></table>
<table style="width:100%;" ><tr ><td width="7%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">2</td><td width="30%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">Name2</td><td width="20%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">Details</td> <td width="43%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">Status OK</td></tr>
</table>        <table style="width:100%;" >        <tr >        <td width="7%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">        3    </td>     <td width="30%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">    Name3    </td>    <td width="20%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">    Details    </td>    <td width="43%" align="center" class="tbcellBorder">    Status OK    </td>    </tr></table>        </div>
```

Tables number increases or decreases depending on the ID number we queried
Now can any body help how to make it as a single table...

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/286047, and edit your questin accordingly.

Comment: SimpleHTMLdom is basically a mere parser though; since you want to do DOM _manipulation_ afterwards, I would recommend using DOMDocument to begin with - SimpleHTMLdom’s methods of manipulating the document are rather rudimentary.

Comment: Could you please give a piece of code for it.. I am a beginner.

Comment: No. SO is not a “gimme code”-type of site. We are happy to help you if you have a specific question or a specific programming problem; but we are not going to solve the whole issue for you, just because you are a “beginner.”

Comment: @CBroe - it seems pretty specific to me, I don't see any problem with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just iterate all the `tr`s and add them to your new table:

```
$str = <<<EOF
<table>
  <tr><td>table 1 - tr 1</td></tr>
</table>    
<table>
  <tr><td>table 2 - tr 1</td></tr>
</table>    
EOF;

$html = str_get_html($str);

$table = '<table>';
foreach ($html->find('tr') as $tr){
  $table .= $tr;
}
$table .= '</table>';

echo $table;
```

Comment: Super @pguardiario...Worked Charmingly... No words to Thank You.. Thanks a Lot